# Ошибка OpenCart 2.3 - magnificPopup is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, opencart, opencart2.0

В OpenCart (OcStore) 2.3 установил модуль для страницы отзывов с изображениями. Есть форма, когда внес данные, загрузил изображение, нажимаешь отправить, никаких действий не производится, при этом в админку отзыв падает. Без изображения, но с остальными полями. Вручную загрузить изображение через админку в отзыв можно.
В консоли браузера увидел ошибку:

TypeError: $('.testimonial-thumbnails').magnificPopup is not a function. (In '$('.testimonial-thumbnails').magnificPopup({
        type:'image'
})', '$('.testimonial-thumbnails').magnificPopup' is undefined)

Magnific Popup при этом подключен. Подскажите пожалуйста, куда смотреть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Инициализация `$('.testimonial-thumbnails').magnificPopup()` происходит раньше, чем подгружается сам `magnific-popup.js`. Либо `jQuery` подгружается позже, чем `magnific-popup.js`. Смотрите код, порядок загрузки длолжен быть таким:

```
jquery.js > magnific-popup.js > $('.testimonial-thumbnails').magnificPopup()
```